# How to pass markdown parameter to javascript file?

Tags: javascript, markdown, hugo, hugo-shortcode

Im using Hugo and Im trying to pass a markdown parameters from md file to JavaScript file.

[This is the markdown file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj6F5.png)

[This is my javascript file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8Rm4.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using your own theme, or something you have downloaded?

You can edit the relevant template to output the parameter as a Javascript variable. And *after that*, use a Javascript function to reference that variable by name. Example:

```
  <script type="application/javascript">
    var title = "{{.Title}}"
    console.log(title)
  </script>
```

In this case, you would probably want to add a check to ensure that parameter exists, or is properly set before trying to print it. Otherwise the JS may throw an error if the variable is null or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Hugo is a static website generator - so it outputs HTML - if you want a "variable" from markdown to Javascript - with traditional JS and Markdown (i.e. no products like Alpine or something beyond the scope of Hugo) you would output the HTML and have Javascript - getElementbyID for instance.